# Remove Permalink Meta Box not working?

Tags: plugin-development, functions, wp-admin

For some reason the slug / permalink meta box is not being removed on the Edit Page screen.

Code in `functions.php`

```
function mjp_edit_meta_boxes() {

    // Remove Meta Boxes
    remove_meta_box( 'commentsdiv', 'page', 'normal' ); // Works
    remove_meta_box('slugdiv', 'page', 'normal'); // Fails?

}

add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'mjp_edit_meta_boxes' );
```

**Update:**

These are the hooks I've tried:

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'mjp_edit_meta_boxes', 1 );  
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'mjp_edit_meta_boxes', 999 );  
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'mjp_edit_meta_boxes', 1 );  
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'mjp_edit_meta_boxes', 999 );
```

Comment: Your exact code works for me... Try two variations of priority `add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'callback', 1);` and `999` instead of *1*. Otherwise, [full troubleshoot](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/troubleshooting-wordpress-35-master-list).

Comment: Is there anyway of instead of hiding it, showing it but stop it from being edited?

Comment: Hid with CSS for now

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue recently on a site that I was modifying for a client. The solution that worked for me was to set a ridiculously high priority for my action hook, like so:

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'mjp_edit_meta_boxes', 999 );
```

This ensures that the action is executed at the very end of the chain after all of the meta boxes have registered.

**Update:**

If this isn't working for you, trying hooking into another action such as `admin_menu`.

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'mjp_edit_meta_boxes' );
```

Comment: Thanks, Unfortunately this doesn't work either :(

Comment: I tried that and add_action( 'admin_menu', 'mjp_edit_meta_boxes', 999 ); with no success. So weird! Im on WordPress 3.5 if they've updated something?

Comment: Either method works for me in 3.5.